# Is there a way to add an additional column after SELECT *?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I would like to SELECT all the columns from my employees table + a an additional calculated column from the same table without manually typing all the columns.

I have thought about this:

```
SELECT *, salary *2 FROM employees;
```

However attempting to do so I get the error:

> 923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: That behavior is according to the ANSI SQL specification. A single `*` must be alone in the select list. To mix with other select list items, do `tablename.*`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to alias the table :

```
SELECT e.*, e.salary *2 FROM employees e;
```

Comment: @AdrianLópezdeLacalle Accept the answer and up vote if the solution worked.

Comment: @NiharikaBitra Unfortunately I cannot do that until I get 15 of reputation. Im completely new to stackoverflow sorry. Hope I could get some.

Comment: @AdrianLópezdeLacalle - you now have 16 rep, and no excuses. :-) But the earlier comment is correct - accepting an answer can be done no matter what your rep score is.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
SELECT employees.*, employees.salary *2 FROM employees;
```